# Render HTML string w/JSX expression in React dangerouslySetInnerHTML()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have successfully used React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render HTML string responses I'm getting from an API, but now I need to add a click handler to parts of certain responses that are set by dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Is there a way to add handlers to dangerouslySetInnerHTML conent? Example:

```
var api_response = '<a onClick={this.props.methodName} href="www.google.com">example</a>';

return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={_markupFromString(api_response)}></div>

function _markupFromString (msg) {
    return { '__html': msg };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work. dangerouslySetInnerHTML() doesn't work with JSX. A better strategy would be to have the AJAX call simply return the required strings and (link and title) and supply a component with these values as props. The component is simply the link in this situation.

Comment: Hey Ken, thanks for the response. I have posted a simplified version of my problem here, but the format of the API responses varies greatly, some requests to the same route return just <p>'s and some <p>'s <a>'s <h1>'s ect, so its really an ambiguous html string. 

If the dangerouslySetInnerHTML() isn't going to work, do you know another approach I can look into?

Comment: It sound like this doesn't need to be a component (or jsx for that matter). I your example the only react requirement is the onClick, can you simply use an href?

Comment: The onclick is for logging, the href needs to do the usual redirect, but be logged by a method in the parent component. The solution might have to be hacky: manually query the dom on component update for these responses that may or may not have an <a></a> in them, and append the event logging handler.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add your SVG in the file public/index.html then create In your component a function like this

```
doSomething() {
 console.log('ajajaj');
}

componentDidMount() {
 window.NameVarible =  this.doSomething;
}
```

And add your event `onClick="NameVariable()"` in the SVG